# Listen for a specific $includeContentLoaded

Tags: angularjs

`$includeContentLoaded` is fired every time `ngInclude` is updated.

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
  // Emitted every time the ngInclude content is reloaded
});
```

What I would like to do, is to listen for a specific `ngInclude` to be loaded, like a callback:

```
$scope.includePath('/path/to/iclude', function() {
  // Fired when the includePath ngInclude have finished loading
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why exactly did I received a downvote?

Answer (score 5):

You can use "onload" tag:

```
<div ng-include="url" onload="test(url)">
</div>
```

And check url in scope function, for example:

```
$scope.test = function(url){
    switch(url) {
        case '/path/to/iclude':
          /*******YOUR CODE***********/
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing something similar, I was searching for a cleaner and more flexible solution, but I can see how this can be improved

Comment: Thank you. This was much more useful to me than using $includeContentLoaded.

Answer (score 3):

in Angular 1.3, you have:

```
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded',function(event,url){
  if (url == 'YourDesiredPath') {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks Raghav. Can you please advice a full specification for the event $includeContentLoaded. I found this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude but I don't know where to find the list of all parameters of the callback function? Thanks you.

Comment: There probably isn't any information about the parameters to the callback function in the documentation. If you want the list of arguments, just log the `arguments` array into the console. http://plnkr.co/edit/EzW4egAYU6LlZ4zMP6ln?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Angular has its own method : $includeContentLoaded

```
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(eve,uri) {
       if(uri == 'views/templates/sample.html'){
        // do something
     });   
   }
```